# What happens with getActivity(), if fragment is out of stack?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I've got a thread that does something with UI. Thread takes a fragment object to start new fragment and things like that. While thread is loading, user may close current fragment and fragment will be out of stack. What will getActivity return for that fragment? I mean in thread. [Doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) says

> Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

Comment: Depending on the lifecycle of the activity it can return null. You can use isAdded and isDetached to check the state of the fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fragment is **detached** from the activity, then `getActivity()` will return null. Remember that fragment's life cycle is bounded with its activity. So if the activity is destroyed, it will return null.